# Unable to show cell count out of total cells in label (eg: 2 of 5) for collectionview in swift

Tags: swift, button, count, uicollectionview

I am scrolling collectionview cells using `leftButton` `rightButton`

initially need to show 1 of 5 tickets

if i tap on rightButton then 2 of 5 tickets, again tap on rightButton then 3 of 5 tickets

now if i tap on leftButton then 2 of 5 tickets like this

**i have tried below code:** `currentItem` using for cells scrolling horizontally, but if i use this for tickets count its not working so i have taken one more variable `ticketCount`  to show ticketCount of total

but with this code thats also not working

if i reached 1 of 5 cells and again if i tap on leftButton then its going to -Ve values as well and total count also exceeds the total count why?

where am i wrong. please guide me.

```
var ticketCount = 1
var currentItem: Int?

@IBAction func leftButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

if currentItem != 0, currentItem != nil {
    
    ticketCount -= 1
    titleLabel.text = "\((ticketCount)) of \(ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count ?? 0) Tickets"
    
    currentItem! -= 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem!, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    
    
} else {
    print("No item to go to previous left")
}
}

@IBAction func rightButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

guard let totalItems = ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count else { return }
if currentItem! < totalItems - 1 {
    
    ticketCount += 1
    
    titleLabel.text = "\((ticketCount)) of \(ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count ?? 0) Tickets"
    
    currentItem! += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem!, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    
} else {
    print("No item to go to next right")
}    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentItem = indexPath.row - 1
}
```

Comment: I think you will find that `willDisplay` is called more often than you think. Either in preparation for a cell which is just off screen, or as a result of manually scrolling. When it is called you are setting `currentItem` and I think it is getting out of sync with your `ticketCount`, allowing it to go negative. Put a print in `willDisplay` and show the index path) to confirm if this is happening.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, if i print indexPath.row in `willDisplay ` then its printing up to 2 only.. its not printing 3. if i have total 3 cells. why?

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, how to solve this issue.. below given answer also not working

Comment: Index path item and section numbers start at 0. 0, 1 and 2 is 3 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few points you need to fix:

- You need to set the initial value of **currentItem** to 0.
- you are decrementing the **currentItem** variable in your leftButton function without checking if it is already at the first item.
- add a condition in your rightButton function to check if currentItem is already at the last item before incrementing.
  your **will Display** function, you are subtracting 1 from the indexPath.row value to set the current Item. simply set **currentItem** to **indexPath.row**.

try this Code by updatin your values

```
var ticketCount = 1
var currentItem: Int = 0 // initialize currentItem to 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
titleLabel.text = "\(ticketCount) of \(ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count ?? 0) Tickets"
}

@IBAction func leftButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
if currentItem > 0 { // check if currentItem is already at the first item
    ticketCount -= 1
    titleLabel.text = "\(ticketCount) of \(ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count ?? 0) Tickets"
    
    currentItem -= 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
} else {
    print("No item to go to previous left")
}
}

@IBAction func rightButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
guard let totalItems = ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count else { return }
if currentItem < totalItems - 1 { // check if currentItem is already at the last item
    ticketCount += 1
    
    titleLabel.text = "\(ticketCount) of \(totalItems) Tickets"
    
    currentItem += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
} else {
    print("No item to go to next right")
}    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
guard let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first else { return }
currentItem = visibleIndexPath.row //updated
//currentItem = indexPath.row //removed line
}
```

Comment: eg: i have total 3 cells and  tried your code initially if i tap left then it becomes 0 of 3 and if i tap right then go up to 2 of 3. then stopes again if i tap left it stops 2 of 3 again if i tap right then it shows 4 of 3 also

Comment: do you need any info from my side let me know will add that code in post

Comment: @swiftdoubts check answer i updated code in collectionView to check and update Currentitem Value in realtime